# Software to copy Windows 10 onto a virtual hard disk for Virtual PC or VMWare

Tags: windows-10, hard-disk, virtualization

My IOmega hard drive used to come with software named *V Clone*, with which I could create images of the whole system. It could also clone a system onto a virtual hard drive.

Unfortunately this company changed into Lenovo and I am not able to find *V Clone* anymore.

I already tried Disk2VHD but this does not make the VHD bootable.

So I am looking for either the V Clone setup somewhere, or an alternative with which I can copy Windows 10 onto a virtual hard disk for Virtual PC or VMWare.

I am after free alternatives only.

Answer (score 1):

You want a system cloning tool like Clonezilla.  You'll need space off of your source disk to save the dump to, and you'll need to boot a VM with a clonezilla disk and access the dump you saved in order to write it back out to the VM's hard drive.  You also may or may not need to do the equivalent of sysprep on it to deal with hardware changes, etc. Of course, those changes may also require you to re-activate the windows license (sorry, dunno about that i'm not a windows user)

Answer (score 0):

The software provided at the link below is an .exe made by Microsoft and therefore runs on Windows.

1. Download the app labeled [1]
2. Open the app (no installation)
3. Wait for it to prepare
4. Click accept after reading the terms/conditions (I didn't read them though)
5. Click installation media for another PC
6. Set your OS/language/architecture, then click next
7. Choose ISO image then next.
8. Select a location to save (just put it in downloads)
9. It should start, it will take a while.
10. You can mount the image as a disk then boot off of it and install it to your virtual drive. Make sure to skip the part where it asks for your product key as it will work perfectly without this.
11. It should be ready to use!

BTW: I use VirtualBox, available at [2].

[1] https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

[2] https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: That will create a fresh copy of Windows. He wants to clone. What about his installed programs, and hsi data?